# py-cord bot sending duplicate embeds

Tags: discord.py, pycord

I've been working on a private discord bot for a week or so now to get familiar with creating discord bots. All of my commands run fine and there are currently no known bugs except this one. For some reason, when my discord bot sends error messages from this function it will send a duplicate of the original embed it sent.
Here is my code:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command_error(self, ctx: commands.Context, error: commands.CommandError):
    
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = '!!! BAD ARGUMENTS !!!', 
            description = f'Please check your arguments and try again. Error: {error}',
            color = 0xFF0000
        )

    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
        
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = '!!! MISSING PERMISIONS !!!', 
            description = f'You do not have permission to use this command.',
            color = 0xFF0000
            )
    
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed (
            title = "!!! ERROR !!!",
            description = "A unknown error has occured. This error has been logged and will be looked into shortly.",
            color = 0xFF0000
        )
        with open("unkown_errors.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(f"{ctx} | {error}\n")
    
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

That code is what I'm using for basic error handling. It will decide the embed based on the error and send the embed at the end of the message. The odd thing is it will send the embed once, and then send the same one again immediately after. It will be the exact same except the embed color on the second one is not the same as the first, it goes back to the default color. I'm unsure of why this is happening and I've tried looking for a solution. Is there any way I can fix this? Screenshot:[image: image of the error]

Answer (score 1):

@Verve!

The method that you are using is incorrect, I think you should try this:-

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command_error(self, ctx: commands.Context, error: commands.CommandError):
    
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = '!!! BAD ARGUMENTS !!!', 
            description = f'Please check your arguments and try again. Error: {error}',
            color = 0xFF0000
        )
        return await ctx.send(embed = embed)

    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
        
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = '!!! MISSING PERMISIONS !!!', 
            description = f'You do not have permission to use this command.',
            color = 0xFF0000
            )
        return await ctx.send(embed = embed)

    else:
        embed = discord.Embed (
            title = "!!! ERROR !!!",
            description = "A unknown error has occured. This error has been logged and will be looked into shortly.",
            color = 0xFF0000
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        with open("unkown_errors.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(f"{ctx} | {error}\n")
            return
```

Mostly this shall work, if it doesn't it might be a bug. If it is a bug please open a issue :- https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/tree/master/

Comment: I tried your method, and the same problem occurs. It is possible that this is a bug with the API. I appreciate your method though, I will implement this into the code. thank you.